# Reset/re-init global variable of a Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

GCP re-uses cloud function instances and as such global vars (class instances) become persistent for the re-used instance.

How to re-init certain global var on each call? (while other global vars could be re-used)

I'm using global vars to pass around params within the code, yet each cloudfunc instance has it's own set of params

Obvious solution: assign those vars to None at the top of the function before assigning to a class instance. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign it the initial value you want at the very start of your function.

Comment: Do you mean at the root level or in a `def main():`?
I'm assigning the value at the root level and GCF is caching the value for the cloud func instance.

Moving to `def main():` is less optimal for me as some of those global values are used by decorators and if I'm to move those vars

BTW. Those global vars are class instances. If that makes any difference.

Comment: At the start of your main function, reset everything that must have a predictable value.

Comment: Yep. Just had the same thought after trying few other options. Please, post the answer separately so that I accept that. Otherwise the initial answer wasn't really clear. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  This is already posted as an answer that you can upvote and accept.